# How to Open XAML file from class file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have three project in one solution.

Project1 & Project2 & Project3.

In Project1 I have two .XAML files.

```
 1. Employee_Account.XAML
 2. Employee_Address.XAML
```

In Project2 I have one .XAML file.

```
 1.ViewEmployee.XAML
```

In Project3 I have one .cs file.

```
1. Method.cs
```

Method.cs --> Method Name

```
Public Void OpenEmployeeScree()
{
}
```

In Project2 --> ViewEmployee.XAML, I have one button click event. Inside this click event i Called Project3 method for OpenEmployeeScree().

E.g:

Project2 :

```
Public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Project3 obj = new Project3();
  obj.OpenEmployeeScree();
}
```

when I click Project3-->ButtonClick event I would like to show Employee_Account.XAML.

How to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This is the code you need.

```
Employee_Account empAcc = new Employee_Account();
MainWindow newWindow = new MainWindow { Owner = this };
newWondiw.Content = empAcc;
newwindow.Show();
```

Comment: Do not forget to add references of projects to call other `Window` from the project.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no idea why you would want to split all these things into 3 separate projects, but you can do this.

```
var acc = Project1_Namespace.Employee_Account();
```